# How to load checked checkbox in ajax edit modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

can you help me how to load checked checkbox in edit modal? I'm using checkbox to input multiple roles in my system. Everything was fine but I have problem in my edit modal. The checkbox was blank and not checked.

this is my ajax edit function:

```
function edit_function(task, id) {
    $('#editModal').modal();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url() . 'user/edit/' ?>' + id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(x) {
            if (resp.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
                    id= x[i]['id'];
                    $("#editModalForm input[name=email]").val(x[i]['email']);
                    $('#editModalForm input[name=role_id]').prop('checked', true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

this is my checkbox in html form

```
<?php foreach ($roles as $row) : ?>
<div class="form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="role_id[]" id="role_id[]"
            value="<?php echo $row->role_id; ?>"><?php echo $row->role_id; ?>
    </label>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

this is my json result:

```
[{"id":288,"role_id":["2","3"],"email":"me@gmail.com"}]
```

Comment: Can you please try this $('#editModalForminput[name^='role_id']').prop('checked', true); ?

Comment: @Hkachhia thank you for your response. i tried it, but it checked all the option

Comment: remove array from id like id=role_id and use id instead of name. It  will fix your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function edit_function(task, id) {
    $('#editModal').modal();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url() . 'user/edit/' ?>' + id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(x) {
            if (resp.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
                    id= x[i]['id'];
                    $("#editModalForm input[name=email]").val(x[i]['email']);
                
                    for (var r = 0; r < x[i]['role_id'].length; r++) {
                        var role=x[i]['role_id'][r];
                         $('#role_id_'+role).prop('checked', true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}


<?php foreach ($roles as $row) : ?>
<div class="form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="role_id[]" id="role_id_<?php echo $row->role_id ?" />
            value="<?php echo $row->role_id; ?>"><?php echo $row->role_id; ?>
    </label>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```